# Index count is always 0 after creating an index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I created an unique index in my MongoDB collection and tried to double check as follows:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> db = pymongo.MongoClient().example
>>> db.my_collection.create_index('uid', unique=True)
u'uid_1'
>>> db.my_collection.indexes.find().count()
0  <- why is it zero?
>>> db.my_collection.indexes.find({"unique": True}).count()
0  <- why is it zero?
```

However, when I insert an item with duplicate 'uid' attribute, it does raise an `DuplicateKeyError` exception:

```
>>> db.my_collection.insert({'uid': 777, 'value': 777})
[ObjectId('552b96......')]
>>> db.my_collection.insert({'uid': 777, 'value': 777777})
.....pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error, { : 777} already exists in unique index
```

What am I missing? How should I list the unique indexes of a collection correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using getindexes() function on a collection?

Comment: is `.indexes` valid? I think the method is `list_indexes` http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes

Comment: @NachiketKate I tried it in the beginning and it keeps complaining that `TypError: 'Collection' object is not callable.`

Comment: @xlembouras Thanks! `db.my_collection.list_indexes()` prints out my 'uid' index ! just curious about why `db.my_collection.indexes.find()` doesn't print out what I want, would be something related to mongodb version?

Comment: In this case `my_collection.indexes` is actually subcollection syntax

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for the info! Could you elaborate more or point me to some good reference for the thing you mentioned? I'm relatively new on mongodb and still trying to digest as much information as  possible.

Comment: They seem to have taken it out of the documentation, but you can see it everywhere, i.e. db.system.namespaces.find() from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/

Comment: This also mentions it slightly from ages ago: http://www.slideshare.net/wildan.m/getting-started-mongodb it is one of those realllllly old features that MongoDB does not advertise anymore and the only way to know is to have used MongoDB for the last 5 years

Comment: Do not query system collections like you tried to do here. You got the name of the `system.indexes` collection wrong and that's why you have no results. Use [`list_indexes`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=index#pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the next code:

```
for index in db.my_collection.list_indexes():
    print(index)
```